# g++/Eclipse wont find include file although path is set

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, g++, opencl

been trying all day to get this to work. I have the AMD APP SDK to do some parallel computing with OpenCL. I set the include path, the library path within my project in Eclipse will keep telling me that the CL.hpp is missing although I can even see it in the includes folder and I can right click on it in the project and see the source code. What is wrong? Even when I try to compile with g++ manually and set the include path with -I it wont work.

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: Wild guess: have you tried replacing the \ by a /?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have the [C++ include path for Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm) set to `/opt/AMDAPPSDK-2.9-1/include` folder (or a project's relative one which corresponds to that one).

Make sure to use forward slashes unix-style (backward ones aren't guaranteed to work correctly) for your include directive

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
```

Comment: The Include is set correctly, otherwise eclipse wouldn't represent the file/folder in question under "includes".

Comment: VS distinguishes between files included in the solution (they might as well be resources) and folders in the include path, that's why I asked to double check. Backward slashes should be the problem anyway.